# Angular: Control that fired ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angularjs-directive

I have an Angular form that has several input boxes that I want to validate, using a generic JS function but need to know the control that fired the event so certain rules can be applied.

(Simplified code)

```
<input ng-model="Field1" ..... ng-change="validateMe()" />
.
.
<input ng-model="FieldX" ..... ng-change="validateMe()" />

$scope.validateMe = function() {
   // get the text of the control that fired the event

   // do the validation 

   // update something else if valid value given

}
```

I know that `ng-click` has the `$event`, but how can I do it from an `ng-change`

Comment: `ng-change` does not have an `$event` created. To my understanding, this is because it is not meant to fire a native change event, but simply evaluate a given expression as a value changes. You should look to binding the event in directive's `link` callback.

Comment: could you explain me what you are going to do with event..could you add some code?

Comment: @Boaz - Sorry... typo and correct

Comment: The intention is that the user inputs a value and it then goes to retrieves the information from a REST service and puts back into the text box the corresponding value.. The form above looks very simple but there's other things around it which i have removed so as not to "muddy the waters"

Comment: I'm trying to replicate my ASP.Net C# days where to have an event handler on `protected void onChange(object Sender, EventArgs e)` and then you have access to the control from `sender` variable

Comment: @ChrisHammond check the updated answer,..Thansk :)

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. Why do you need the target element? Normally don't need that in angular. Also why aren't you using angular built in validation?

Comment: from the description you provided, I suspect that you may have issues with application scaling.  I know you were already provided an answer, but you really should consider if this is really something you want to do.  Performing a network call to an API service every time there is a change to your input box is going to perform very poorly, and using it on multiple input boxes could bind your server up with literally hundreds or thousands of unnecessary network calls.

Comment: @Claies Your comments are perfectly valid but in this instance, as its an internal company form used by one department, I know the server loads will be extremely low ... Fair comment though!

Comment: @ChrisHammond you might be surprised, this feels like a [$asqwatch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbcJfg-d5nI), if, let's say, the input box averages someone typing 10 characters, then you are making 10 network calls for one result.  I would definitely at least use `ng-options` to add a debounce or `updateOn: blur`....

Comment: @Claies correcting its `ng-model-option` which could have debounce to some miliseconds..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have you own custom directive that will call your controller method on custom change event.

**Markup**

```
<input ng-model="Field1" my-custom-change change-method="validateMe(event)">

<input ng-model="FieldX" my-custom-change change-method="validateMe(event)">
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('myCustomChangeEvent', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      changeMethod = '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      element.on('change', function(event){
        scope.changeMethod({event: event});
        scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: The OP probably wants a reference to the target element, not just its value.

Comment: @ChrisHammond Glad to hear that..Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this in the `ng-change`.  I would do this validation with an attribute directive instead.  This way you have full access to the element in question and can apply custom validation rules based on that.

```
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {

            ngModel.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                if (isElementInQuestion(elm) {
                    ngModel.$setValidity('myCustomValidMessage', scope.validateField(value));
                }
                return value;
            });
        }
    };
```